# CallKit CallDirectory extension failing to block calls

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I'm developing an app with database of blocked numbers.

Below is the code where I retrieve the numbers, sort them and call the `addBlockingEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber:)` method of `CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext`:

```
private func addAllBlockingPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {
    // Retrieve all phone numbers to block from data store. For optimal performance and memory usage when there are many phone numbers,
    // consider only loading a subset of numbers at a given time and using autorelease pool(s) to release objects allocated during each batch of numbers which are loaded.

    var allPhoneNumbers: [Int64] = []
    if let numbers = PhoneNumber.fetchAll(context: ctx){
        for number in numbers {
            if allPhoneNumbers.contains(number.number) == false {
                allPhoneNumbers.append(number.number)
            }
        }
    }

    for phoneNumber in allPhoneNumbers.sorted(by: <) {
        context.addBlockingEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: phoneNumber)
    }
}
```

The error content is `nil` when the extension is reloaded, so it should be working.

Inbound calls on iPhone SE (iOS 12.2), iPhone 7 (iOS 12.4.1 and iOS 13.1.3) and iPhone 8 (iOS 13.1.2 and 13.1.3) are blocked as expected, but on iPhone XS/ XS Max (iOS 13.1.2 and iOS 13.1.3) they are allowed through.